# JWT Authorize Attribute is not working php

Tags: php, codeigniter, jwt

I am facing on get to `token` in `authorize token`.

```
$lthis=& get_instance();
$token = $lthis->input->get_request_header('Authorization');
```

not get to `token` value but locally is working. any idea!

Comment: Are you sure that the `Authorization` header exists in your production environment test in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the $_SERVER superglobal. Something like this might suffice:

```php
$headers = [];

foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
  if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') {
    $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value;
  }
}

echo $headers['Authorization'];
```